# Exporting an applet as jar

Tags: java, jar, applet, calculator

Hi everyone I made a calculator applet and am trying to export it as a JAR file, since you can't export applets as runnable JARs. When I try to do java -jar Calculator.jar in command line though I get an error "saying no main manifest attribute, in Calculator.jar". I'm wondering if I need to do anything else in my main method other than below to fix this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
}
```

Comment: What do you want "java -jar Calculator.jar" to do?

Comment: I want it to start the Calculator applet.

Comment: You need to do some basic research. See my answer.

Comment: If I want to be able to run it outside of a webpage, like as a .exe, would I need to make it a JFrame instead of an applet?

Comment: Yes, to make an applet into an application you need to build a window with swing. It also uses main instead of the run method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use an applet, you have to [embed it in a webpage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/html.html).

Here's some HTML for your use case.

```
<applet code = 'PACKAGE.Calculator' 
 archive = 'Calculator.jar'
 width = 300
 height = 300>
 <param name="permissions" value="sandbox" />
</applet>
```

Fill in PACKAGE with your package for the applet and modify the height/width to fit.